# Specify callback function in enet

Tags: c++, enet

The ENet library has packets that can be send, and includes a callback function once it has finished sending that specific packet.

http://enet.bespin.org/structENetPacket.html#ad602d6b6b35ef88b2b2e080fa5c9dc3d

```
typedef struct _ENetPacket
{
   size_t                   referenceCount;  /**< internal use only */
   enet_uint32              flags;           /**< bitwise-or of ENetPacketFlag constants */
   enet_uint8 *             data;            /**< allocated data for packet */
   size_t                   dataLength;      /**< length of data */
   ENetPacketFreeCallback   freeCallback;    /**< function to be called when the packet is no longer in use */
   void *                   userData;        /**< application private data, may be freely modified */
} ENetPacket;
```

The callback itself:

```
typedef void (ENET_CALLBACK * ENetPacketFreeCallback) (struct _ENetPacket *);
```

Now I want to create a class that holds the host used to send those packets, and also to keep track how many packets were successfully sent.

```
template<typename T>
class Sender {
    public:
        explicit Sender() { }
        void send(T* data, int32_t length)
        {
            ENetPacket* packet = enet_packet_create(data, length, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
            packet->freeCallback = callbackPacket;
            enet_host_broadcast(m_server, 0, packet);
        }
        
        void callbackPacket(ENetPacket* packet)
        {
            --m_counter_packets_active;
        }
};
```

This does not compile: `Error C3867 Sender<int32_t>::callbackPacket': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

When I try

```
packet->freeCallback = &this->callbackPacket;
```

I get `Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'void (Sender<int32_t>::* )(ENetPacket *)' to 'ENetPacketFreeCallback'`

I just don't understand what the proper code would be for the packet calling the Sender object's method when the packet is done with.

Comment: you can't cast member functions as simple function pointers, see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types

Comment: `callbackPacket` should be `static` method, and you might probably get "`this`" from `packet->userData` (that you should feed at registration too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is pretty common. First, you can't call a non-static member method this way, not directly. Pain in the ass.

But that callback structure has a userData field. And that's what we're going to use.

```
 void send(T* data, int32_t length) {
     ENetPacket* packet = enet_packet_create(data, length, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
     packet->freeCallback = &Sender::myStaticMethod;
     packet->userData = this;  // This is part of the magic
     enet_host_broadcast(m_server, 0, packet);
 }

 static void myStaticMethod(ENetPacket * packet) {
     Sender * sender = static_cast<Sender *>(packet->userData);
     sender-> callbackPacket(packet);
 }
```

In other words -- store `this` as your user data. Use a static method for the callback, and have him turn it around to call your real callback.

Comment: Aah, nice, this works! Thank you so much!